# Generic Type Trait example

Tags: c++, c++14

I want to check that a some type has some methods:

```
using Arg_t2 = int;
using Arg_t3 = int;

template<class T>
struct ValidType{
   using Ret_t1 = T;
   using Arg_t1 = int;
   // ...
   Ret_t1 method1(Arg_t1,Arg_t2,Arg_t3);
   //...
};
```

Therefor I wrote a type-trait:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class T,class _ = void> struct is_my_valid : ::std::false_type {};
template<class T> struct is_my_valid<T,::std::enable_if_t<
  ::std::is_same<typename T::Ret_t1,decltype(::std::declval<T>().method1(::std::declval<typename T::Arg_t1>(),::std::declval<Arg_t2>(),::std::declval<Arg_t3>()))>::value
  // && ...
> > : ::std::true_type {};
```

We can test this with:

```
static_assert(is_my_valid<ValidType<int>>::value,"");
```

What are my options to make the definition of `is_my_valid` this look prettier?

Edit:
I basicly want to describe an Interface with type traits. I want to do this, because the interface includes types, that depend on template parameters.

I also like that an type does not have to be implemented using the ValidType in anyway to be valid.

Comment: Is [a C++20 `concept`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) an option for you?

Comment: @Edward It is not a solution at the moment, since I am limited to c++14. But I will have look, since the day may come ...

Comment: Couldn't you use something like `template<class T> struct has_trait : std::false_type {};` and `template<class T> struct has_trait<ValidType<T>> : std::true_type {};`? This seems much more concise, though I admit that it implies more "manual" labor. Maybe it would help to give more context to better judge how appropriate your solution is.

Comment: @Edward the `requires` expression looks like it would make this a lot prettier.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** Only after posting did I see that the question was tagged `c++14`. This code relies on `std::void_t` from `c++17` which is trivial to implement in `c++14`.

You can extract some of the functionality to a reusable `detect` type-trait that only needs to be supplied a type alias to work.

```
namespace detail {

template <template <class...> class CheckTemplate, class = void, class... Object>
struct detect_impl : std::false_type {};

template <template <class...> class CheckTemplate, class... Object>
struct detect_impl<CheckTemplate, std::void_t<CheckTemplate<Object...>>, Object...> : std::true_type {};
}  // namespace detail

template <template <class...> class CheckTemplate, class... Object>
constexpr bool detect_v = detail::detect_impl<CheckTemplate, void, Object...>{};
```

With that in place all we need is to use it as such.

```
template <class T>
using is_valid = decltype(std::declval<T>().method1(0, 0, 0));

template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_valid_v = detect_v<is_valid, T>;

static_assert(is_valid_v<ValidType<int>>)
```

The `Object` pack let's us make a more flexible `is_valid` that takes the argument types as parameters if we want.

```
template <class T, class... Args>
using is_valid_flex = decltype(std::declval<T>().method1(std::declval<Args>()...));

template <class... Args>
constexpr bool is_valid_flex_v = detect_v<is_valid, Args...>;

static_assert(is_valid_flex_v<ValidType<int>, int, int int>);
```

Additional modification is possible if we want to involve the return-type of the method.